# From Msi , how to get the list of files packed in each feature?

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer, powershell-2.0

We have used wix to create Msi. Each Msi will be having 1 or 2 or 3 features such as Appserver feature, Webserver feature and DB server feature.

Now i was asked to get the list of config files presented in each feature.

It is tough to find the list of web.config files associated with each feature through wxs file.

Is it possible find the list of files associated with a feature with particular search pattern?

For ex. Find all the web.config files packed in Appserver feature.

Is there any way easy way ( querying or some other automated script such as powershell) to get the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wix comes with a .NET SDK referred to as the DTF ("deployment tools foundation"). It wraps the windows `msi.dll` among other things. You can find these .NET `Microsoft.Deployment.*.dll` assemblies in the SDK subdirectory of the Wix Toolset installation directory. The documentation is in `dtf.chm` and `dtfapi.chm` in the doc subdirectory.

As shown in the documentation, you can use this SDK to write code which queries the msi database with SQL. You will be interested in the [Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [FeatureComponents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tables.

If you haven't explored the internals of an MSI before, you can open it with [orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making slight modifications to the [`Get-MsiProperties` function described in this PowerShell article](http://www.snowland.se/2010/02/21/read-msi-information-with-powershell/).

Please read the original article and create the prescribed `comObject.types.ps1xml` file.

```
function global:Get-MsiFeatures {
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,HelpMessage="MSI Database Filename",ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Alias("Filename","Path","Database","Msi")]
        $msiDbName
    )

    # A quick check to see if the file exist
    if(!(Test-Path $msiDbName)){
        throw "Could not find " + $msiDbName
    }

    # Create an empty hashtable to store properties in
    $msiFeatures = @{}

    # Creating WI object and load MSI database
    $wiObject = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer
    $wiDatabase = $wiObject.InvokeMethod("OpenDatabase", (Resolve-Path $msiDbName).Path, 0)

    # Open the Property-view
    $view = $wiDatabase.InvokeMethod("OpenView", "SELECT * FROM Feature")
    $view.InvokeMethod("Execute")

    # Loop thru the table
    $r = $view.InvokeMethod("Fetch")
    while($r -ne $null) {
        # Add property and value to hash table
        $msiFeatures[$r.InvokeParamProperty("StringData",1)] = $r.InvokeParamProperty("StringData",2)

        # Fetch the next row
        $r = $view.InvokeMethod("Fetch")
    }

    $view.InvokeMethod("Close")

    # Return the hash table
    return $msiFeatures
}
```

Comment: `[System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'InvokeMethod'.`